# Django How to find out if earlier than 7pm in a specific timezone

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm new to Django/programming and am trying to write some code that would tell me if it is earlier than 7pm in a specific timezone (I would provide the timezone).

I apologize if this type of question has been asked a lot. I searched for an answer but couldn't come up with a solution.

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Comment: I was able to find a solution that works: tz = timezone('US/Eastern') datetime.now(timezone(tz)).hour<19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution that works:

```
tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
datetime.now(timezone(tz)).hour<19
```